# local variable referenced before assignment blender

Tags: python, blender

This is part of a function I have in python for blender, but whenever I run the script it says that yz_slope is not assigned but there is no error for xy_slope and I declared yz_slope within the function. What is the problem?

```
def execute(self, context):
    obj = context.active_object
    if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        vertices = bm.verts

    else:
        vertices = obj.data.vertices

    verts = [obj.matrix_world * vert.co for vert in vertices] 

    plain_verts = [vert.to_tuple() for vert in verts]
    print(plain_verts)
    rdomain_list = [x[0] for x in plain_verts]
    domain_list = rdomain_list[:]
    domain_list.sort(reverse=False)
    domain_list[:] = [x - domain_list[0] for x in domain_list]
    xstart = domain_list[0]
    for i, var in enumerate(domain_list):
        if i == len(domain_list) - 1:
            xend = var
    print(xstart, xend)
    ry_list = [x[1] for x in plain_verts]
    y_list = ry_list[:]
    y_list.sort(reverse=False)
    y_list[:] = [x - y_list[0] for x in y_list]
    ystart = y_list[0]
    for i, var in enumerate(y_list):
        if i == len(y_list) - 1:
            yend = var
    print(ystart, yend)
    rz_list = [x[2] for x in plain_verts]
    z_list = rz_list[:]
    z_list.sort(reverse=False)
    z_list[:] = [x - z_list[0] for x in z_list]
    zstart = z_list[0]
    for i, var in enumerate(z_list):
        if i == len(z_list) - 1:
            zend = var
    print(zstart, zend)
    if rdomain_list[1]==rdomain_list[0]:
        xy_slope = 'undefined'
        y_int = 'none'
        x_int = rdomain_list[0]
        if ry_list[1]==ry_list[0]:
            yz_slope = 'undefined'
            z_int = 'none'
        else:
            yz_slope = (rz_list[1]-rz_list[0])/(ry_list[1]-ry_list[0])
            z_int = rz_list[0]-ry_list[0]*yz_slope
    else:
        xy_slope = (ry_list[1]-ry_list[0])/(rdomain_list[1]-rdomain_list[0])
        y_int = ry_list[0]-rdomain_list[0]*xy_slope
        if ry_list[1]==ry_list[0]:
            yz_slope = 'undefined'
            z_int = 'none'
        else:
            yz_slope = (rz_list[1]-rz_list[0])/(ry_list[1]-ry_list[0])
```

Line that has the error. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'yz_slope' referenced before assignment

```
            z_int = rz_list[0]-ry_list[0]*yz_slope
```

Comment: y'know, it would probably be helpful if you showed the rest of the function **and** the stack trace which tells you what error, what line number, etc...

Comment: it is a long function but I will add the line and error

Comment: Running the code as a plain script I can't get it to produce an error. Check for simple things, is this the exact function that the error comes from? Is this from the same file that produces the error? Do you still have an old version running within blender? meaning does your addon unregister the old operator version before loading the new version.

Comment: It started working suddenly but it does unregister the old one before loading the new version.